# diable click outside of dialog box using simple javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable click of outside of datas which have background of modal box.I try to use many time but it didn`t success.How can I do that?I tested that code

```
  $('#myModal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
})
```

but it disabled background and modal box.I want to show modal box, I want to disable background data only.

**here is my code**

```
 function openDialog() {
        $("#aging_dialog").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            modal: true, //モーダル表示
            width: 402,
            height: 530,
            buttons: [ //ボタン
                {
                    text: "設定",
                    class: 'dialog_Btn',
                    click: function () {
                        pushConfirm();
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: "キャンセル",
                    class: 'dialog_Btn',
                    click: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            ]               
        })
        $('#aging_dialog').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false, show: false })          
    }
```

Comment: Try using an element that covers the entire background/screen (transparent), that sits between the modal and background data, then capture the clicks/keyboard there.

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI ([`.dialog()`](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)), or Bootstrap ([`.modal()`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/))?

Comment: Did you try setting the backdrop and keyboard via `data-*` attribute? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#options